# How to suppress Login error warning in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

In the PowerBuilder code, I'm curious how to suppress the warning message as shown below when we enter wrong password. I'm using messagebox to display "Invalid Password" which the only message I want to see. 
It usually occurs after this statement connect using SQLCA;

But I don't want below message to appear on my screen. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
"Connection failed:
 SQLState: '1500'
 SQL SERVER ERROR: 0
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL SERVER DRIVER] Invalid connection string attribute
Connection failed:
SQLSTATE: '28000'
SQL Server Error: 18456
```

Comment: We have to make a few assumptions about your situation, but it sounds like the code in your app is producing a MessageBox() with contents you don't want. To the best of my knowledge, PB won't do this by itself, so I'm assuming it's the code in your app. If you share that code, maybe someone can identify some options.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an error coming from whatever Datawindows you have when you are doing the connect.

In the "DBError" event of the DW, put "return 1".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. I solved this issue by passing ConnectOption with SQL_Driver_NOPROMPT value in DBParm.